# UserAuthentication via Flattr-REST: No PIN returned?

Tags: api, flattr

I'm trying to write a new application using the Flattr REST-API version 1 (not the beta v2). The application acquires a request token at first, which seems to work properly. But I run into a problem authenticating the user. The link created for authentication looks like this:

```
https://api.flattr.com/oauth/authenticate?access_scope=read,click&oauth_token=MY_REQUEST_TOKEN
```

Clicking the link everything seems alright. Information about the application and the scope requested is shown, but clicking "Authenticate", there's no pin code, but the following error from `https://flattr.com/apps/pincode/MY_REQUEST_TOKEN`:

> Something went wrong. Please try again

BUT now the Application IS in the authorized application list of the user though that doesn't really help if the user can't get the pin code...

The Application type is set to client. It's the first time I try to work with the API so I'm not sure if I miss anything important? Would be grateful for some help.

Just as an update: We finally changed to API v2. Getting Authorization for our application feels a bit clumsy, as we set the redirecturi to some webpage, where we display the returned code and let the user copy&paste it into our client application... we kind of made our own pincode-flow :/

Comment: Are you using the old API or the beta of the new Flattr API (https://developers.flattr.net/v2/)?

Comment: I'm using the old API, should I switch to the beta? // just added the info in opening post

Comment: I found the same problem on the old Flattr-Forum (http://forum.flattr.net/showthread.php?tid=666). Back then (february) it was fixed by flattr. I guess it's probably the same bug again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, please use the v2 api, which uses oauth2 + bearer token.

However, the new API doesn't support authentication using the pincode flow.

As stated by Maike this is probably a bug that has surfaced yet again :(
I'll create an internal bug ticket and try to get it fixed.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Do you know if there are any plans to add the pincode flow to the v2 api? We are writing a small client application (as an add-on for some existing application), which does not need a webserver by itself. Setting up a webserver just for the authentication seems rather absurd :( So if the pin flow for v1 is gonna be fixed, we will probably use v1 as long as possible

Comment: it should be fixed by now. please try and get back to us if it's not working :)

Answer (score 0):

The pincode isn't a feature planned. You can use the oauth2 "implicit grant" to authenticate the resources owner. This isn't documented at the moment but is possible.

When you do the request to https://flattr.com/oauth/authorize you pass the response_type `token` instead of `code`. This will append a access_token fragment in your callback URL. In your http client it might be possible to catch the 302 from our server and parse the access_token from the fragment.

All this requires a http client in your application whom you can control the flow inside your app.